# Jupyter notebook autocomplete unavailable when using new environment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda

I have recently created a separate environment with conda. In this new environment, when I open jupyter notebook, clicking Tab to show autocomplete or suggestion doesn't work at all. There seem to be no obvious way to enable it.

Comment: What version of `jupyter` and related packages (show output from `conda list '(jupyter|notebook)'`)?

Answer (score 0):

using this line in your jupyter notebook help.

%config Completer.use_jedi = False